# Create table on Javascript with numbers from up to down

Tags: javascript, html-table, element

I want to create a table on Javascript from 0 to 49. I want the numbers to be displayed on the table from up to down, but I'm unable to correctly create the elements in order to get my desired result. My actual code is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            var number = 0;
            var div = document.getElementById("internal");
            var table = document.createElement("table");
            div.appendChild(table);

            for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

                var rows = document.createElement("tr");
                table.appendChild(rows);

                for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {

                    var columns = document.createElement("td");
                    var text = document.createTextNode(number);
                    columns.appendChild(text);
                    rows.appendChild(columns);
                    number++;
                }
            }

            document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0].setAttribute("border", 2);
            document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0].children[0].children[0].setAttribute("style", "background-color: red;");
            document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0].children[0].children[0].innerHTML = "";

        </script>
```

This code right here creates the table almost the way I want, but instead I want the rows to be the columns. I know it may be a dumb question but I'm totally unable to get it the right way.

Comment: please add an example of the wanted table. what means *up to down* and *rows to be the columns*?

Comment: Brakebein got It right, but thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do a little calculation in this statement:

```
var text = document.createTextNode(number);
```

instead of simply incrementing the number (which will inevitably increase going down the row, not down the column).

Try this:

```
var text = document.createTextNode(i + (j-1)*5);
```

Some test values to show how this works, where `i` is the row number and `j` is the column number:

```
+---+---+-------------+
| i | j | output      |
+---+---+-------------+
| 1 | 1 | 1 + 0 = 1   |
| 2 | 1 | 2 + 0 = 2   |
| 3 | 1 | 3 + 0 = 3   |
| 1 | 2 | 1 + 5 = 6   |
| 1 | 3 | 1 + 10 = 11 |
+---+---+-------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Just iterating a number doesn't do the trick. You need to consider the length of the rows in combination with the current row and column indices.

```js
var rowLength = 5;
var colLength = 10;

for (var i = 0; i < rowLength; i++) {

  var rows = document.createElement("tr");
  table.appendChild(rows);

  for (var j = 0; j < colLength; j++) {

    var columns = document.createElement("td");
    var text = document.createTextNode(i + j * rowLength);
    columns.appendChild(text);
    rows.appendChild(columns);

  }
}
```

Here is also a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ey7hfzfq/

Comment: Thats right, It makes sense, but I didn't made up my mind to be able to get to that. Thanks a lot.

Comment: No problem. If it solved your problem, please accept this answer.